# Property 'myForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
import { Component, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-contact-form',
    templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.css'],
})

export class ContactFormComponent implements OnInit {

    myForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    createForm() {
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3),
                Validators.maxLength(50)
            ])],
            email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
            gender: ['', Validators.required],
            terms: ['', Validators.requiredTrue]
        });
    }

}
```

#### Error

```
Error: src/app/contact-form/contact-form.component.ts:15:5 - error TS2564: Property 'myForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.       
  15     myForm : FormGroup;
           ~~~~~~
 src/app/contact-form/contact-form.component.ts:17:10 - error TS2565: Property 'myForm' is used before being assigned.
    
 17     this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move

```
   this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
```

After form creation

```
   this.myForm = this.fb.group
```

Because you try to subscribe for form before it creation

```
  createForm() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), 
Validators.maxLength(50)])],
    email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
    gender: ['', Validators.required],
    terms: ['', Validators.requiredTrue]
     });

this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)   }
```

Comment: thankyou but this error stay      
    Error: src/app/contact-form/contact-form.component.ts:15:5 - error TS2564: Property 'myForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.    
    15     myForm : FormGroup;
           ~~~~~~

Comment: But this error says that you don’t move valueChanges inside createform function. Just move inside and on ngOnit call createform function

Answer (score 7):

The error is connected with TypeScript's strictPropertyInitialization. It might be fixed the following way:

```
  myForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)])],
    email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
    gender: ['', Validators.required],
    terms: ['', Validators.requiredTrue]
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
```

(Realisation is taken from the Angular's [Reactive Forms Guide](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), they provide [live example](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/reactive-forms/stackblitz.html) there and that's how they do it in profile-editor.component.ts)

Answer (score 4):

The default angular template now has `strictPropertyInitialization` set to true in the `tsconfig` file.

You can do 2 things:

- apply the best practice of initializing the properties, either inline or in the constructor
- disable the `strictPropertyInitialization` flag in your tsconfig file (not recommended)

Information: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization

Comment: thankyou but the type is formgroup i cant initialize and when i add ! others errors appear

Answer (score 4):

add this to your code:  // @ts-ignore , like that:

```js
// @ts-ignore
editForm: FormGroup;
```

```
myForm: FormGroup;
```

Answer (score 3):

here, **non-null** assertion operator could help us to prevent the type checker from throwing error.

```
myForm!: FormGroup;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `createForm()` code inside the constructor of the component. Before you do this `this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);`

Ideally you should have the form creation in constructor and keep your subscriptions in `ngOninit()`